# How can I disable notifications in the pulldown but keep status bar icons, for a specific app?

Tags: notifications, notification-bar, notification-icons

I have an app that gives me the current date in a non-Gregorian calendar. It has a permanent notification (I can't swipe it away to dismiss it) that I see in the pulldown notification area and an icon in the status bar. I only want to see the status bar icon. How can I do that?

Comment: Only possible if the app settings have that option

Comment: I don't think it's possible since the requirement to show an icon on the status bar for 3rd-party apps is to have a notification instead...